# Push segue hiding navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I have two view controllers, I added `navigation bar` to `second view controller` with two bar button items `Back` and `Item` as shown below
[image]

But when I do a `push segue` from `first view controller`, it is replaced by `navigation item <Category`, which is `title` of `navigation item` in my `first view controller` as shown below
[image]

How do I keep my `navigation bar` intact avoiding the default `navigation item <Category`, which is being added automatically while maintaining push segue functionality.

I tried to do maually without using stoyboard as follows

```
@IBAction func plusAction(_ sender: Any) {
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC") as? SecondViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController!, animated: true)
}
```

but it still doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to display two bar button items `Back` and `Item` by added `UINavigationBar` to second view controller, you are doing it in the wrong way!!!

In your storyboard, drag a `UINavigationItem` to your second ViewController.

> If the `UINavigationItem` does not display on your storyboard, you must select second view controller, choose `Opaque Navigation Bar` or `Translucent Navigation Bar` (not important)

After that, you can drag `UIBarButtonItem` where you want on your ViewController

Comment: I did what you told but it doesnt work, it still hides the navigation bar and dispalys <Category back button.

Comment: @Coder221 Do you want display back button with `Back` text instead `Category` text?

Comment: @Coder221 first, you shouldn't create new `UINavigationBar`, the `UINavigationBar` will auto inherit from first ViewController. After that you doing like my answer. Then in your storyboard draging a `UIBarButtonItem` to the left of your sencond ViewController as name Back

Comment: If I do like that it is sending UIBarButtonItem to the bottom of the ViewController

Comment: @Coder221 how to you create `UINavigationBar` in your first ViewController? Draging a `UINavgationBar` to your first ViewController is wrong way. In your storyboard, you must select your first ViewController, `Editor` -> `Embed in` -> `Navigation Controller` like this: [link](https://ibb.co/dCUcEm)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161565/discussion-between-coder221-and-tuan1dreamm).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the kind of segue through segue inspector (click the particular segue and check its attributes in the inspector) like this,

[image]
But you should know each one of it is not similar, has it's own definition in how it appears - check https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

Also, alternatively using code,

```
if let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "storyboardId") as? TargetViewController {
            self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that but I want Push functionality, so your answer will be of no help.

Comment: Did you use the code there, it will work like pushing segue